# Filtering NULL values in date field in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, filter, null

In QGIS 3.16.9 I would like to find all the locations that have a `NULL` value. It is for a date field in the field services Drains dataset. I have been searching the use of `NULL` around various forums.

This is what I have put in so far.

[image]

Seems a very straight forward thing to ask, basically I want to show where the Depot team need to visit, and raise a flag to see where they need to visit next to prioritise the work.

Comment: BERA that worked first time, great to have some help once and a while

Comment: Yes it does.  @Taras Pefect..

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax for fields with null values is:

```
"last_date" is null
```

And the reverse:

```
"last_date" is not null
```